# How do I save results into .txt file

Tags: java

I am using MAC OS and I would like to save my results into a .txt file but for some reasons its not outputting a .txt file. This is the code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int one = 1514;
    int zero = 396;
    for (int i = 0; i <= one; i++) {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= zero; x++) {
        System.out.println("0");
    }      

}
```

What the code does it simply outputs 1514 1's (as specified in int one variable) and underneath 1's it outputs 0's (as specified in int zeros variable). I want whatever is printed (both 1's & 0's) to be saved in .txt file. I found this code online but how do I combine into my code so that it prints first 1's and 0's?

```
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
 out.println();
 out.close();
```

Comment: this will print on the console, not write in a text file

Comment: Recommended reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: @maraca Yes thats true - I want the results to write in a .txt file

Comment: @user3812613 i see, somehow overlooked the last part, just wanted to know if that is the main problem or the algorithm

Comment: System.out is connected to stdout, you could redirect stdout to a file when you run your program. "java MyClass > my_file.txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int one = 1514;
    int zero = 396;
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt"); //create PrintWriter
    for (int i = 0; i <= one; i++) {
        out.println("1"); //Write "1"
    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= zero; x++) {
        out.println("0"); //Write "0"
    }  
    out.close(); //close PrintWriter    

}
```

This will write to the text file instead of printing it out. You will get the same thing in the text file as your code was printing. I hope I understood your question right BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print to the PrintWriter, as I've shown below

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
      out.println();
      int one = 1514;
    int zero = 396;
    for (int i = 0; i <= one; i++) {
        out.println("1");
    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= zero; x++) {
        out.println("0");
    }
    out.close();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `System.out.println("1")`, declare your PrintWriter above the `for` loops and say `out.println("1")` or zero instead.